# Identity Server 3 - Entity Framework stops connecting to MySQL after few successful login

Tags: c#, mysql, azure, entity-framework-6, identity

I am using Identity Server 3 with mysql, So I define the mysql connection string and the login works for few times and after that it stops working and I get error from Identity server. This happens after deployed to azure.

**Please note that there is no issue with my connection string as it works for first few logins.**

Looking further I could see that the EF fails to connect to mysql. I tried restating the azure website, but no luck. So I looked at my mysql server and I could see idle connection from azure IP in the client connection list. I manually stopped the connection using MYSQL workbench and then again it starts working. But after few successful login the problem repeats.

Here is the error I could see in my trace file

```
Unhandled exception accessing: /identity/login
System.Data.Entity.Core.ProviderIncompatibleException: An error occurred accessing the database. This usually means that the connection to the database failed. Check that the connection string is correct and that the appropriate DbContext constructor is being used to specify it or find it in the application's config file. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=386386 for information on DbContext and connections. See the inner exception for details of the failure. ---> System.Data.Entity.Core.ProviderIncompatibleException: The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string. ---> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Open()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Create(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.CreateNewPooledConnection()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetPooledConnection()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.TryToGetDriver()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetConnection()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices.GetDbProviderManifestToken(DbConnection connection)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.GetProviderManifestToken(DbConnection connection)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.GetProviderManifestToken(DbConnection connection)
   at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbProviderServicesExtensions.GetProviderManifestTokenChecked(DbProviderServices providerServices, DbConnection connection)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbProviderServicesExtensions.GetProviderManifestTokenChecked(DbProviderServices providerServices, DbConnection connection)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DefaultManifestTokenResolver.<>c__DisplayClass1.<ResolveManifestToken>b__0(Tuple`3 k)
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DefaultManifestTokenResolver.ResolveManifestToken(DbConnection connection)
   at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbConnectionExtensions.GetProviderInfo(DbConnection connection, DbProviderManifest& providerManifest)
   at System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbConnection providerConnection)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModel(LazyInternalContext internalContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryLazy`2.GetValue(TInput input)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider()
   at System.Data.Entity.QueryableExtensions.FirstOrDefaultAsync[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Data.Entity.QueryableExtensions.FirstOrDefaultAsync[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.UserStore`6.<GetUserAggregateAsync>d__6c.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at IdentityServer3.AspNetIdentity.AspNetIdentityUserService`2.<FindUserAsync>d__19.MoveNext() in F:\VSO\Porto.la\Portola API\Portola.IdentityServer\App_Packages\IdentityServer3.AspNetIdentity\IdentityServer3.AspNetIdentity.cs:line 0
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at IdentityServer3.AspNetIdentity.AspNetIdentityUserService`2.<AuthenticateLocalAsync>d__21.MoveNext() in F:\VSO\Porto.la\Portola API\Portola.IdentityServer\App_Packages\IdentityServer3.AspNetIdentity\IdentityServer3.AspNetIdentity.cs:line 0
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at IdentityServer3.Core.Endpoints.AuthenticationController.<LoginLocal>d__9.MoveNext() in c:\ballen\github\identity\IdSrv3\IdentityServer3\source\Core\Endpoints\AuthenticationController.cs:line 234
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.System.Web.Http910911.TaskHelpersExtensions.<CastToObject>d__3`1.MoveNext() in c:\ballen\github\identity\IdSrv3\IdentityServer3\source\Core\Configuration\Hosting\NoCacheAttribute.cs:line 0
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext() in c:\ballen\github\identity\IdSrv3\IdentityServer3\source\Core\Configuration\Hosting\NoCacheAttribute.cs:line 0
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext() in c:\ballen\github\identity\IdSrv3\IdentityServer3\source\Core\Configuration\Hosting\NoCacheAttribute.cs:line 0
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext() in c:\ballen\github\identity\IdSrv3\IdentityServer3\source\Core\Configuration\Hosting\NoCacheAttribute.cs:line 0
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<ExecuteActionFilterAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext() in c:\ballen\github\identity\IdSrv3\IdentityServer3\source\Core\Configuration\Hosting\NoCacheAttribute.cs:line 0
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext() in c:\ballen\github\identity\IdSrv3\IdentityServer3\source\Core\Configuration\Hosting\NoCacheAttribute.cs:line 0
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext() in c:\ballen\github\identity\IdSrv3\IdentityServer3\source\Core\Configuration\Hosting\NoCacheAttribute.cs:line 0
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<ExecuteActionFilterAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext() in c:\ballen\github\identity\IdSrv3\IdentityServer3\source\Core\Configuration\Hosting\NoCacheAttribute.cs:line 0
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext() in c:\ballen\github\identity\IdSrv3\IdentityServer3\source\Core\Configuration\Hosting\NoCacheAttribute.cs:line 0
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.<ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsyncCore>d__2.MoveNext() in c:\ballen\github\identity\IdSrv3\IdentityServer3\source\Core\Configuration\Hosting\NoCacheAttribute.cs:line 0
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.<ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsyncCore>d__2.MoveNext() in c:\ballen\github\identity\IdSrv3\IdentityServer3\source\Core\Configuration\Hosting\NoCacheAttribute.cs:line 0
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.AuthenticationFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__0.MoveNext() in c:\ballen\github\identity\IdSrv3\IdentityServer3\source\Core\Configuration\Hosting\NoCacheAttribute.cs:line 0
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__0.MoveNext() in c:\ballen\github\identity\IdSrv3\IdentityServer3\source\Core\Configuration\Hosting\NoCacheAttribute.cs:line 0
```

Below are the asp.net identity related classes

```
public class CustomIdentityDbContext : IdentityDbContext<CustomIdentityUser>
{
    public CustomIdentityDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public static CustomIdentityDbContext Create()
    {
        return new CustomIdentityDbContext();
    }
  }

public class CustomIdentityUser : IdentityUser
{
    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class CustomUserStore : UserStore<CustomIdentityUser>
{
    public CustomUserStore(DbContext ctx)
       : base(ctx)
    {
    }
}

public class CustomUserManager : UserManager<CustomIdentityUser>
{
    public CustomUserManager(IUserStore<CustomIdentityUser> store)
        : base(store)
    {
    }
public static CustomUserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<CustomUserManager> options, IOwinContext context)
{
    var manager = new CustomUserManager(new CustomUserStore(context.Get<CustomIdentityDbContext>()));
    // Configure validation logic for usernames
    manager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<CustomIdentityUser>(manager)
    {
        AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false,
        RequireUniqueEmail = true
    };

    // Configure validation logic for passwords
    manager.PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator
    {
        RequiredLength = 6,
        RequireNonLetterOrDigit = true,
        RequireDigit = true,
        RequireLowercase = true,
        RequireUppercase = true,
    };

    // Configure user lockout defaults
    manager.UserLockoutEnabledByDefault = true;
    manager.DefaultAccountLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
    manager.MaxFailedAccessAttemptsBeforeLockout = 5;

    // Register two factor authentication providers. This application uses Phone and Emails as a step of receiving a code for verifying the user
    // You can write your own provider and plug it in here.
    manager.RegisterTwoFactorProvider("Phone Code", new PhoneNumberTokenProvider<CustomIdentityUser>
    {
        MessageFormat = "Your security code is {0}"
    });
    manager.RegisterTwoFactorProvider("Email Code", new EmailTokenProvider<CustomIdentityUser>
    {
        Subject = "Security Code",
        BodyFormat = "Your security code is {0}"
    });
    manager.EmailService = new EmailService();
    manager.SmsService = new SmsService();
    var dataProtectionProvider = options.DataProtectionProvider;
    if (dataProtectionProvider != null)
    {
        manager.UserTokenProvider =
            new DataProtectorTokenProvider<CustomIdentityUser>(dataProtectionProvider.Create("ASP.NET Identity"));
    }
    return manager;
}
}
```

Below is the identity server 3 configurations

```
 app.Map(
                "/identity",
                coreApp =>
                    {
                        var factory =
                            new IdentityServerServiceFactory()
                                .UseInMemoryClients(Clients.Get())
                                .UseInMemoryScopes(Scopes.Get());
                        factory.ViewService = new Registration<IViewService, IdentityCustomViewService>();

                        factory.Register(new Registration<CustomIdentityDbContext>());
                        factory.Register(new Registration<UserStore<CustomIdentityUser>>(x => new CustomUserStore(x.Resolve<CustomIdentityDbContext>())));
                        factory.Register(new Registration<UserManager<CustomIdentityUser, string>>(x => new CustomUserManager(x.Resolve<UserStore<CustomIdentityUser>>())));
                        factory.UserService = new Registration<IUserService, AspNetIdentityUserService<CustomIdentityUser, string>>();

                        coreApp.UseIdentityServer(
                            new IdentityServerOptions
                            {
                                SiteName = "Identity Server",
                                SigningCertificate = Cert.Load(),
                                Factory = factory,
                                RequireSsl = true,
                                AuthenticationOptions = new IdentityServer3.Core.Configuration.AuthenticationOptions
                                {
                                    EnablePostSignOutAutoRedirect = true,
                                }
                            });

                    });
```

Comment: Are you using PaaS?

Comment: @SA For mysql I use a dedicated server. I hope that is what you asked. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please check your code and make sure you have disposed the database context when you are done with it. Not doing so will exhaust your Connection Pool and you may fail to get a connection. You could do it with using statement. Code below is for your reference.

```
using (var dbContext = new YourMySqlDbContext())
{
    //do something with your dbContext
}
```

Comment: Yes we do use using statements. But you know in Identity server app we are not using our context at any place. we just pass the type of our context as dependency injection. So I hope Microsoft is using using statements internally. I have no control over it. See the code we use for configuration factory.Register(new Registration<IdentityDbContext>());

Comment: Which types of UserStore and UserManager did you use? Did you implement them by yourself.

Comment: Hi Amor I have updated my question with all the details

Comment: I can't find any issue in your code. Try adding Pooling=false to your connection string to disable the connection pool.